# Java: Is there a way to use a method defined in a superclass, along with added functionality in the subclass?

Tags: java, inheritance

I have a superclass *A* which contains an **inset()** function, and a subclass *B* that also contains an **insert** function. Is there a way to utilize the A's insert() method in B, along with some other statement's added to B's insert() function?

Comment: You can call the superclass method from the subclass method by using the `super` keyword. See: [Using the Keyword `super`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html)

Comment: If you want to enforce it at the superclass level, see the [Template Method Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern#Structure).